# How to observe all programmatical changes of textarea content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, textarea

I'm developing a chrome extension for Blogger.com, and I need to perform some actions when textarea with post is changed programmaticaly by Blogger modules. For example after image insert. Some changes made by raw XmlHttpRequest, other made in some mystical way that I don't understand.

jQuery on change, on input etc don't work, because changes aren't made by user. MutationObserver doesn't catch any mutations related to textarea, because they aren't affect DOM. Periodically check textarea value looks like brute workaround for me. Right now, I'm observing moment when specific modal windows, for example image upload windows is closed, and then check whether textarea value was changed. But this mutation can easily occur in other circumstances too.

Is there any more appropriate technique?

Comment: probably not if you don't have direct access to the code making changes

Comment: Have you tried something like: `document.querySelector('#postingComposeBox').contentDocument.body.addEventListener('input', function(e){ console.log(e) });`? You'll be notified when the user write something. You will also have access to iframe's MutationObserver I believe.